# Clearing Textbox does not set binding to null

Tags: wpf, data-binding, textbox, null

I am having difficulty setting an empty TextBox to null on an nullable DB Field.

XAML

```
<y:TextBox Text="{Binding Year1Cost, Mode=TwoWay,  
     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,   
     NotifyOnValidationError=True,   
     ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,   
     ValidatesOnExceptions=True,  
     StringFormat=\{0:c\}}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
```

When I enter any value into it the binding is fine and the entered value is passed
When I leave a null value alone a null is passed
If I delete the value from the TextBox the value passed is the Original value of the Textbox and the UI is not notified of the change `Grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr`

I have spent a long time checking out options
nothing short of putting code behind the OnTextChanged of every nullable field I cannot see the efficiency in doing this.

Thanks in advance:

ps.  Have looked at TargetNullValue to no success

Visual Studio 2008 - SP1 - .Net 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using a [value converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx).  You should be able to implement the ConvertBack method to translate empty strings into nulls.

Comment: Had to convert to a space, as an empty string did not trigger property changed event for some reason.  Thank you for your help, I will implement on all required places.

Answer (score 15):

Set the property `TargetNullValue` of the binding to `String.Empty`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}"/>
```

I tried it and it works for me.

And if I am not wrong (please forgive me if I am), you should set the property StringFormat like this:

```
StringFormat={}{0:C}
```

This is even probably the reason of the exception you got.

Comment: xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" I tried this but keep getting Error 24 Could not load type 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Metadata.ProvideMetadataAttribute' from assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Design.Extensibility, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Line '1' Position '6680'.

Comment: I donno.
But if I would be you, I would try just for a test to have a TextBox without the other definitions; just binding and TargetNullValue.
This way can help you find the source of the exception.

Comment: Tried removing the StringFormat all together and I am still getting the same meassage. --- <TextBox Text="{Binding Year1Cost, TargetNullValue={x:Static sys:String.Empty}}" /> ---- That is all I have and still get the above exception

Comment: I honestly donno :( I wish I could help you

Answer (score 3):

For me only converter works :
Here's [a link](http://blog.jtango.net/binding-a-textbox-to-a-nullable-value-type-in-wpf)

```
public class NullableConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       return value == null ? string.Empty : String.Format(culture, "{0}", value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       return string.IsNullOrEmpty(String.Format(culture, "{0}", value)) ? null : value;
    }
}
```